# Why is my variable unaffected by certain built-in functions if it stores data read from a file?

Tags: kdb

I have a file called `01.in`, in the same folder I'm running q. It contains one line, which has a string of digits in it. For instance, let's assume it contains the following string: `1122`.

I read the data from this file, transformed it into a list of integers digits, and stored it in a variable `a` using the following line:

```
a:("i"$read0 `:01.in)-"i"$"0"
```

Now if I try to use some dyadic built-in functions such as `xprev` or `rotate`, the q interpreter outputs either nothing, or the original list. For example:

```
q)a
1 1 2 2
q)-1 xprev a

q)0 xprev a
1 1 2 2
q)1 xprev a

q)-1 rotate a
1 1 2 2
q)0 rotate a
1 1 2 2
q)1 rotate a
1 1 2 2
```

Those same functions work if I use them on the list `1 1 2 2` directly. I'm trying to understand why what I'm doing isn't working as I expected. Just a heads up: I'm very new to q, so I apologize if this is something obvious that I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the way you are reading the file, you are creating a nested list:

```
q)type a
0h
q)0N!a;
,1 1 2 2i
```

Here I use `0N!` to show the raw structure, the `,` indicates this is a nested list. Instead, try reading it something like this:

```
q)a:"I"$'first read0`:01.in
q)a
1 1 2 2i
q)-1 xprev a
1 2 2 0Ni
```